# How to create path redirections

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, uri, permalinks

I want to create internal path redirections like in Wordpress e.g.

if i have a post (having `permalink = 'hello-world')` but still if I type `'http://localhost/hello/'`, I get redirected to `'http://localhost/hello-world'`

So what code do i use to automatically go to that page with that correct URI, i.e. **change the URI that gets displayed in the address bar.** Perhaps this is something other than using .htaccess rules (except the use of it for facilitating the basic presence of permalinks)??

perhaps this question might be a little trivial but i couldn't seem to find effective help on google.